# Calcular exponente - Diferencia entre pow() y **

Tags: python

Lo dicho en el título, he encontrado dos maneras de calcular el exponente en python y ambas me funcionan,

```
a = 2
print (a**2)
print (pow(a,2))
```

Ambas dan lo mismo, ¿Cual es la diferencia?¿Cuando emplear una u otra?

¡Salud y gracias!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tanto `**` como `pow()` pueden usarse para calcular potencias enteras o fraccionarias. Por ejemplo, `2**0.5` te dará la raíz cuadrada de dos, y `pow(2,0.5)` lo mismo.

La diferencia fundamental es que `pow()` <strike>*siempre* convierte sus argumentos a float y retorna un resultado float</strike> (no, ver actualización). En cambio `**`, cuando detecta que sus argumentos son enteros, realiza aritmética entera. Esto puede ser mucho más rápido para potencias pequeñas y, por otro lado, puede producir resultados de precisión arbitraria para exponentes grandes (con todas las cifras significativas que sean necerias).

Por ejemplo, compara los resultados de `pow(2,1000)` y `2**1000`.

```
>>> math.pow(2, 1000)
1.0715086071862673e+301
>>> 2**1000
1071508607186267320948425049060001810561404811705533607443750
3883703510511249361224931983788156958581275946729175531468251
8714528569231404359845775746985748039345677748242309854210746
0506237114187795418215304647498358194126739876755916554394607
7062914571196477686542167660429831652624386837205668069376
```

**Actualización**

Parece que `pow()` también puede usar aritmética entera cuando los operandos son enteros. Esto no era así en versiones previas de python, debe de ser una optimización más reciente, pero puede verse que `type(math.pow(2,2))` produce `int`, por lo que probablemente sea equivalente a `**`, salvo cuando se trata de números grandes, que `pow()` representa en coma flotante pero `**` pasa a usar "big ints".

**Actualización 2**

Otra diferencia es que el operador `**` se puede "sobrecargar". Es decir, puedes definir una clase que implemente un método `__pow__()` que es invocado por el intérprete cuando encuentre `ej ** n`, si `ej` es un objeto de esa clase (y entonces le pasa `n` como parámetro). En cambio `math.pow()` requiere forzosamente que sus argumentos sean numéricos.

Ejemplo de esto último:

```
class P:
  def __init__(self, a, b):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b

  def __pow__(self, n):
    return (self.a + self.b)**n


ej = P(1, 2)
print(ej**2)
```

Y sale `9`. Mientras que:

```
print(math.pow(ej, 2))
```

produce el error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 14, in <module>
TypeError: must be real number, not P
```

Answer (score 1):

Tal como lo planteas en el ejemplo, no hay ninguna diferencia en usar una forma u otra. si consultamos la [documentación](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#pow):

> Return x to the power y; if z is present, return x to the power y,
>   modulo z (computed more efficiently than pow(x, y) % z). **The
>   two-argument form pow(x, y) is equivalent to using the power operator:
>   x**y**.

**Es decir, en la forma de `x` elevado a la `y`, ambas son equivalentes**. Por como se implementan, `**` seguramente involucre más código que `pow()`, hay que recordar que `**`  representa una implementación interna de algunos objetos, del  metodo `__pow__` (eventualmente `__rpow__`, `__ipow__`), pero el impacto, seguramente es indistinguible.

Las únicas diferencia que podrían ser significativas en otras circunstancias:

- `pow()` ofrece un tercer parámetro `z` para obtener el módulo, usando la notación binaria, es decir `**` sería `(x ** y) % z`, en caso de usar la función, sería `pow(x, y, z)`, esta forma, podría ofrecer una mejora marginal en la performance.
- El uso del operador binario, podría eventualmente generar alguna confusión, ej:  `-2**2` en realidad, por un tema de precedencia de los operadores, no es el cuadrado de `-2` sino `-(2**2)`, para escribirlo correctamente: `(-2)**2`. Usando la función no haría falta recordar esto: `pow(-2, 2)`

**Importante**: Estamos comparando la función incluida `pow()` con el operador binario `**`, también existe otra implementación en `math.pow` que no entra en esta respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Se usa ** para calcular potencias de enteros exactos, por otro lado pow() convierte los argumentos en tipo flotante.

Puedes encontrar mas información aquí: https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html